# Build error for simulator with swift package dependency. "Cannot open file handle for file at path: .framework"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I made a simple blank project and added **Bugsee** via *swift-package-manager*.

Its located on https://github.com/bugsee/spm.

I can successfully build project for iOS Device.

But it fails for Simulator. And the error is not really verbose
(the path is shortened):

```
Cannot open file handle for file at path: Path(str: ".../Bugsee.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/Bugsee.framework")
```

***What does it mean?***

The path is valid and the framework is there:
[image]

I also found that build for simulator is OK after I have added Bugsee.xcframework into *Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content*.
[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I use Xcode 12.5.1

Comment: Same happens with Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SPM in Xcode have an issue with i386 arch.
Bugsee released 1.28.0 with dropped support for i386 arch. And now Xcode starts building fine for simulator.
I think i should create a ticket in SPM tracker.

Comment: I am experiencing the same/similar issue, with a locally added XCFramework, Xcode 13.3, when all 3 conditions are true: (i) Simulator, (ii) Release build, (iii) SPM:

```'/Users/{PATH}/{FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework' is missing architecture(s) required by this target (arm64), but may still be link-compatible.```

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately, i haven't found the solution. SPM forum left my question without answers :(